# How to resolve "JSONDecodeError" when using LinkedIn API in Python?

Tags: python, json, linkedin-api

I'm trying to access the LinkedIn API in Python and I've been able to successfully obtain an access token and instantiate an `application` object using the `linkedin` library.

```
# Set up LinkedIn API credentials and scope
LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID = "myappclientid"
LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET = "myappclientsecret"
REDIRECT_URI = 'https://localhost:8000'
SCOPE = ['r_emailaddress', 'r_liteprofile', 'w_member_social']

# Create LinkedInAuthentication object with credentials and scope
authentication = linkedin.LinkedInAuthentication(
                    LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID,
                    LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET,
                    REDIRECT_URI,
                    SCOPE
                )

# Get the authorization URL to prompt user to grant access
authorization_url = authentication.authorization_url
print(authorization_url)

# User should visit the URL and be redirected to a localhost URL with a 'code' parameter
response_url = input("Please enter the redirected URL:")
parsed_url = urlparse(response_url)
query_params = parse_qs(parsed_url.query)
code_param = query_params.get('code', [None])[0]

# Set authorization code in the authentication object to retrieve access token
authentication.authorization_code = code_param
access_token = authentication.get_access_token()
print("Access token:", access_token[0])

# Create LinkedInApplication object with access token
application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(token=access_token[0])

# Try to get the user's profile with the LinkedInApplication object
try:
    application.get_profile()
except Exception as e:
    print("Error: ", e)
```

However, when I try to use any of the LinkedInApplication methods, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/models.py", line
971, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py",
line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py",
line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py",
line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None 
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char
0)
 
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/linkedin/utils.py", line 56,
in raise_for_error
```

Can anyone help me understand what's causing this error and how I can fix it so I can access the LinkedIn API?

Comment: The library isn't maintained anymore and broken.

Comment: I see, that explains the behaviour then. What can I use instead of it?